# Haskell Num Instance

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell so I apologize if I am overlooking something basic, but I am creating a Coord type that has three parameters: Position, Vector, and Scalar. Coord must be an instance of Num and must have specific implemented methods in it. I believe I have what I need already, but I'm assuming I'm missing something basic because I get an error based on the Num instance.

My code:

```
data Position x y = Position (x, y)
data Vector x y = Vector (x, y)
data Scalar n = Scalar n
data Coord x y n = Coord (Position x y, Vector x y, Scalar n)

instance Num Coord where
    negate (Position (x, y)) = Position (-x, -y)
    negate (Vector (x, y)) = Vector (-x, -y)
    (+) (Vector (a, b) Position (x, y)) = Position (x+a, y+b)
    (+) (Vector (a, b) Vector (c, d)) = Vector (c+a, d+b)
    (+) (Scalar x Scalar y) = Scalar (x+y)
    (*) (Vector (a, b) Scalar c) = Vector (a*c, b*c)
    (*) (Position (x1, y1) Position (x2, y2)) = (x1*x2) + (y1*y2)
    (*) (Scalar x Scalar y) = Scalar (x*y)
    (-) (Vector (a, b) Position (x, y)) = Position (x-a, y-b)
    (-) (Position (x1, y1) Position (x2, y2)) = Vector (x2-x1, y2-y1)
    (-) (Scalar x Scalar y) = Scalar (x-y)
    abs (Position (x, y)) = Scalar sqrt((x*x)+(y*y))
    abs (Vector (x, y)) = Scalar sqrt((x*x)+(y*y))
    signum _ = error "undefined"
    fromInteger _ = error "undefined"
```

The error I get:

```
Expecting three more arguments to ‘Coord’
The first argument of ‘Num’ should have kind ‘*’,
  but ‘Coord’ has kind ‘* -> * -> * -> *’
In the instance declaration for ‘Num Coord’
```

Any clarification on how to use Num would be much appreciated (I'm assuming that is what's responsible for the error)

Thank you.

Comment: There are very many issues with this code. You shouldn't try to write large amounts of code at once like this; now you're getting errors and you don't know which part of the code you've written is at fault!

Comment: The error you're getting refers to the `instance Num Coord where` line: you probably want something like `instance (Num x, Num y, Num n) => Num (Coord x y n) where`. This is because `Num` expects a fully "filled-out" type as its argument: you can write an instance `Num Int` or `Num (Maybe Int)`, but not `Num Maybe` or `Num []`.

Comment: But really, your design looks very weird, and I wouldn't even bother fixing this; what are you actually trying to achieve, what kind of code do you want to write with this? You say you're "creating a Coord function that has three parameters [...]" but clearly you've defined `Coord` as a type, not a function.

Comment: It is confusing to me too. A `Coord` has a `Position`, a `Vector` and a `Scalar` inside of it (which would add up to a five dimensional value)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to the type system with Haskell. Coord is supposed to be its own type and I want to be able to do the operations that are seen in the apparently pseudo code above.

Comment: First of all try to express your types in plain English (in the way you think about it) and write it down. After that try to rewrite it in the way of a haskell type system. If you'll succeed with this two steps it would be easy to implement it in code.

Comment: For example: "Position is a type which consists of two integers" -> "Position is a type with a single constructor that accepts two integers" -> "data Position = Position Int Int"

Comment: Don't get frustrated, but at the moment your problem is not with Num typeclass. Before getting there, you should create better types (Position,Vector,Scalar,Coord) as the currrent definitions clearly do not represent what you expect them to.

Comment: @zudov thank you for the help. I will try your recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into the suggestions I finally cam up with a solution that works.

```
data Coord = Position (Double, Double) | Vector (Double, Double) | Scalar Double deriving (Show)

instance Num Coord where
    negate (Position (x, y)) = Position (-x, -y)
    negate (Vector (x, y)) = Vector (-x, -y)
    (+) (Vector (a, b)) (Position (x, y)) = Position (x+a, y+b)
    (+) (Position (x, y)) (Vector (a, b)) = Position (x+a, y+b)
    (+) (Vector (a, b)) (Vector (c, d)) = Vector (c+a, d+b)
    (+) (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = Scalar (x+y)
    (*) (Vector (a, b)) (Scalar c) = Vector (a*c, b*c)
    (*) (Scalar c) (Vector (a, b)) = Vector (a*c, b*c)
    (*) (Position (x1, y1)) (Position (x2, y2)) = Scalar((x1*x2) + (y1*y2))
    (*) (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = Scalar (x*y)
    (-) (Vector (a, b)) (Position (x, y)) = Position (x-a, y-b)
    (-) (Position (x, y)) (Vector (a, b)) = Position (a-x, b-y)
    (-) (Position (x1, y1)) (Position (x2, y2)) = Vector (x2-x1, y2-y1)
    (-) (Scalar x) (Scalar y) = Scalar (x-y)
    abs (Position (x, y)) = Scalar (sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)))
    abs (Vector (x, y)) = Scalar (sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)))
    signum _ = error "undefined"
    fromInteger _ = error "undefined"
```

Hopefully this helps anyone in the future that is making the same mistakes as me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in a word: parentheses.

instead of

```
negate Position (x, y) = Position (-x, -y)
```

do

```
negate (Position (x, y)) = Position (-x, -y)
```

The former implicitly implies that `negate` is a function which takes two arguments - the `Position` value constructor and `(x,y)`, rather than a single argument of type `Position`, since it parses it as

```
((negate Position) (x,y)) = ...
```

Your other function definitions have the same problem.

Comment: I don't think that's what the error says. To be an instance of `Num` your type needs a kind `*`, but his Coord has a kind `* -> * -> * -> *`.

Comment: Mephy: whoops I didn't even read that far! I just saw the obvious parsing problem.

Comment: Thank you and I apologize if there are multiple issues. I am new to Haskell and it all seems so different than what I'm used to.

Comment: no need to apologize - it was all new to everyone at one point

Comment: @rampion I added the parenthesis that you pointed out and I'm still getting the same error.